# What are the combinations of "there-is" or "there-are" called in English grammar terms?

Tags: terminology, existentials

What are the combinations of "**there-is**" or "**there-are**" called in English grammar terms?

> For example: **There is** an apple on the table.

I am looking for a specific term for these expressions (as well as for the same in past tense such as "**there was**" and "**there were**").

Normally in many of languages, unlike in English these two combinations are expressed in one specific word.

Comment: If you're looking for the equivalent of the Spanish "hay" or the French "il-y-a," then I'm afraid you won't find it.  As a native English speaker, I've found it cool that other languages express "there is" as a single word, but English just doesn't do that.

Comment: @CanadianYankee - Technically, *il-y-a* isn't one word either; you could gloss it as "he-there-has".  :-)

Comment: @standon - Of course you're correct.  I suppose you could say that English has the contraction **there's**, which is as much one word as *il-y-a* is. In casual conversation, many people even use **there's** as a contraction for **there are**, even though that's not strictly correct.

Comment: **Il y a** is both **there is** and **there are** and is invariable (can be followed by a singular noun or plural noun). No dashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called  "[**existential clause**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_clause)", "[**existential sentence**](http://www.oxfordbibliographies.com/view/document/obo-9780199772810/obo-9780199772810-0070.xml)", or "[**existential construction**](http://www.oxfordbibliographies.com/view/document/obo-9780199772810/obo-9780199772810-0070.xml)" or simply [**existential**](http://www.oxfordbibliographies.com/view/document/obo-9780199772810/obo-9780199772810-0070.xml). 
This terms refer for all tenses of the existential clauses, such as: there is, there are, there was, there were, there will etc.

> **Existential** (n. & adj.) (A grammatically *marked *structure) typically
>   used to express a *proposition that someone or something exists.
>   An existential *construction (also called a there-existential) typically
>   conforms to the following pattern:
>
> *there* + (*auxiliary / raising verb*) +  *be* + notional subject.
>
> The unstressed *pronoun there is a *dummy subject called existential
>   there. Here are some examples:
>
> There is an emergency
>
> There must be a God
>
> There seems to be no solution
>
> These are called **bare existential clauses**, which do not have a
>   nonexistential counterpart (cf. *An emergency is).
>
> An **extended existential clause** contains additional material
>   (called the extension), such as a *locative (1) or *temporal phrase, a
>   *relative clause, a *to-infinitive, or an *-ing clause:
>
> There is a mouse in the loft
>
> There was a fire last week
>
> There has been nothing in the papers about this
>
> Can there be life on other planets?
>
> There’s one student who brings her dog to class
>
> There is a great deal of work to do
>
> There was a fox running down the street

(The Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar. P.147)

Comment: That's exactly what Lambie said in their answer. Forget the "clause" bit, the essential answer is EXISTENTIAL. Lambie even posted a link to Thoughtco.com. Admittedly the answer could have been formatted better but you could have done that yourself.

Comment: Did you even bother to look at the two links in Lambie's answer? And I cannot believe looking up **existential sentence** you found nothing.

Comment: Lambie is a woman...not that it matters, I prefer to use "they" in anycase. Did you click on the first link? did you? What does it say? When a user posts one or more links, as the OP, you should be motivated to click on those links to see if they support the answer. Both links support Lambie's answer. I edited and added an excerpt from the second link.

Comment: After seeing your comments I've changed my mind and edited my answer. You're right and unlike I thought before. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

*There is* and *there are* [*there exists* etc.] are called **existential sentences** or utterances. ***There*** is called a *dummy* subject.

> There are apples on the table.

There is at least one entire book on the subject:
*Existential Sentences in Englis*h (RLE Linguistics D: English Linguistics) 1st Edition
by Gary L. Milsark (Author)

[**dummy subject**](http://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/grammar-lesson-dummy-there.php)

[**existential sentence**](https://www.thoughtco.com/existential-sentence-grammar-1690689)

> In English grammar, an existential sentence is a sentence that asserts the existence or nonexistence of something. For this purpose, English relies on constructions introduced by *There* (known as the "existential there").

From David Crystal's, *Making Sense of Grammar*. Pearson Longman, 2004

> The term **existential sentence** is an attempt to capture the meaning conveyed by the following type of construction:
>
> - *There's a strange cat in the garden*
>     *There were lots of people in town.*
>     *There weren't any apples on the tree*.
>     *There appeared a bright star in the sky.*
>
> The word *there* comes first . . .. It is then followed by the simple present or past tense of *be*, or a small range of 'presentational' verbs, such as: *appear*, *arise*, *ascend*, *come*, *emerge*, *erupt*, *exist*, *float*, *occur*, *spring up*, *stand*. The noun phrase following the verb is usually indefinite, as shown by such words as *a* and *any*. . . .

Comment: I didn't go into it in detail as the question was: what are these called. It was not examples of those sentences, just what they are called.

Comment: I think you focus on the OP's request and forget that answers should also help other users and (casual and non) visitors alike. The two links are excellent but they were easy to miss if someone didn't understand that existential sentence (and/or *clause*) is the answer. On Stack Exchange, I find that "more" is better unless the answer gets ridiculously long-winded and verbose.  And I see no harm in citing a short excerpt from a link

Comment: @Mari-LouA Citations are fine, long or short. But you took a liberty I myself would not take. I might ask someone to put one in, but not go to the publication and choose one on their behalf.

Comment: You can rollback the edit if you feel I overstepped the line. Nonetheless, the excerpt was taken from  your 2nd link.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I will not roll it back, now it's there. I know it is from my link. Perhaps next time you can ask me to add additional stuffing to my answer. :)

Comment: I did once, remember the Swiss watch, you didn't want to even add a link or cite a dictionary definition. I promise I won't edit your answers again.

Comment: I believe strongly that some answers do not merit a dictionary definition. Others do. This particular one does merit more explanation unlike regular idioms that are just in an English speaker's head.

Answer (score 1):

The constructions "there is" or "there are" are called [**expletive constructions**](http://reword.ca/what-are-expletive-constructions-and-why-should-i-avoid-them/) or [**expletive syntax**](http://coursesite.uhcl.edu/HSH/Whitec/INST/expletive.htm).

Comment: Thank you, but I see that this term is not specific for "there is" and "there are". This is what your source states: "expletive constructions are phrases or sentences that begin with “There are,” “There is,” **“It is,**” or **“It was.**”" (normally in a lot of languages, unlike in English these two combinations are expressed in one specific word)

Comment: If you're looking for something that refers **only** to "this is" and "there are", I'm not sure you're going to find one...

Comment: I found something new regarding to it:  https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/163669/12430